# How to hide sections titles while keeping chapter titles

Tags: sectioning, chapters, fancyhdr, titlesec, report

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

%header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[R]{Strona \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{10pt}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum[2-8]

\section{section}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

I want to hide every section title in document without deleting them from ToC, i want to keep them only in header `\fancyfoot[L]{\leftmark}`. In footer i want to have only title of chapter without numbering "CHAPTER 1." etc.

Comment: Hide section titles? As in have `\section{<section title>}` in your code, but it doesn't set anything other than in the ToC and the headers? Or do you just want to remove the section *numbering*?

Comment: Hi! Your code doesn't help much in understanding what you want to achieve, and is missing the body (between `\begin` and `\end{document}`), so it's not readily usable. In the future try posting minimal but _working_ examples of code, it will be much easier to get answers!

Comment: I've edited post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to achieve what you're after: Both the `\chapter` and `\section` macros have been overwritten to just perform the necessary insertions (or lack thereof).

```
\documentclass[oneside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[R]{Strona \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}% Header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}% Footer rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}% Make plain page style match fancy

\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  % Print the chapter title
  \begin{center}
    \Huge\bfseries #1
  \end{center}
  % Add entry to ToC
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{#1}% Update Left footer
  \fancyhead[L]{}% Clear Left header (sectional unit)
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  \par
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  % Don't print sectional unit; just add to ToC and update the Left header
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \fancyhead[L]{#1}% Add chapter title in Left header
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \csname @starttoc\endcsname{toc}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum[2-8]

\section{section}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what i was looking for. <3 Thank you and Happy New Year.

Comment: I have another problem that i'm not able to solve :C With page style like that good solution would be starting new page every section. When i'm adding \clearpage in `\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%...` i'm getting huge space between chapter title and first section. Do you know how could i avoid that?

Comment: @Wernexnrs: I can't replicate that behaviour when I add `\clearpage` as part of the new `\section` (just replaced `\par` with `\clearpage`). Can you provide more detail? Something that replicates that problem that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an ugly workaround, but until you get a better answer from more experienced users, you can:

- hide the name of the section by simply writing nothing;
- hide the section number using the `titlesec` package;
- have the section title show up in the table of contents anyway by explicitly writing it as an option.

So, all in all, your sections may look something like: `\section*[Title for the ToC]{}`, and you should add

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
```

to your preamble to hide the section numbers (while still keeping them in the ToC).

This is a minimal working example, i took away all of your code that wasn't strictly necessary, but of course you can put it back.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Pizza}
\section{Visibly talking about pizza}
Pizza is good.
\section[Secretly talking about pizza]{}
Pizza is very good
\end{document}
```

It should give you this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I want to hide section titles with numbers without integration in ToC and chapter titles.
I wanted to use `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}` and then `\titleformat{\section}{}{}{0pt}{}` but with that i can't edit titles style of my chapters.